# Expected scalar value: MATLAB Coder

Tags: matlab, matlab-coder

I get the following error while using MATLAB coder for generating a c++ code from m file with a call to a c function ompmex.c

C function calls always return scalar values but a non-scalar value is expected here.

My code is:

```
function [D,gamma] = DSGD2(X,H) %#codegen

   [Xr,Xc]=size(X);
   [Hr,Hc]=size(H);

   D=zeros(Hr,Hc,'double');
   D=X(:,11:210);
   d1=sqrt(sum(D.*D)); D=D./repmat(d1,Xr,1);

   beta=zeros(Xr,Xc,'double');

   beta=coder.ceval('ompmex',H,X,H'*H,200);
```

Can anybody help on this. I am not getting a working answer online

Comment: Please anyone.....who can help

Comment: It would help to know the C signature of `ompmex`.  The message is saying that a C function cannot return an array however `beta` is assigned to have size `Xr-by-Xc`.

Comment: i don't have much experience with C. But what do you mean by signature of ompmex. All i understand is that ompmex is a c function trying to return a variable not acceptable by MATLAB

Comment: There should be a header file (a `.h` file) that lists a declaration for `ompmex`.  Something like `double ompmex(double, into, double);`.  Another question, is `ompmex` a MEX file?  You would have a file named `ompmex.mex...` where the ... may be a letter and the number 32 or 64 like `.mexa64`.

Comment: I also see that you referenced `ompmex.c` in your question.  Can you see the function declaration (something like `double ompmex(double, int, double);`) in that file?  Seeing the way `ompmex` is declared is necessary to advise on how to invoke it via `coder.ceval`.

Comment: Hi... I saw the code. In fact there are two c files. First ompmex.c is setting parameters so that the second function ompcore.c can be used with different settings of parameters. ompmex uses double *variable name and definition of ompcore.c is like this: mxArray* ompcore(double D[],.......)

Comment: Also i found one solution: coder.opaque('double'). By declaring my output variable of type opaque my code compiles fine, but now the output being opaque is non usable, even for basic operation like + - * due to variable type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

```
function [D,gamma] = DSGD2(X,H) %#codegen

   [Xr,Xc] = size(X);
   [Hr,Hc] = size(H);

   D = zeros(Hr,Hc,'double');
   D = X(:,11:210);
   d1 = sqrt(sum(D.*D)); 
   D = D./repmat(d1,Xr,1);

   % coder.ceval is tricky. I recommand to use it only if the function is
   % created by c-coder too (and not as mex function!)! you need a c executable
   % or a c library (generated before you trigger codegen for DSGD2). 
   % further more, ceval can not handle multiple
   % outputs. as a workaround, always use structs for output - and for
   % input too!
   s = struct('beta',(zeros(Xr,Xc,'double')));
   % make it work in matlab too and call ompmex function
   if coder.target('MATLAB')
       s = ompmex(H,X,H'*H,200);
   else
       coder.ceval('ompmex_initialize')
       s = coder.ceval('ompmex',H,X,H'*H,200);
       coder.ceval('ompmex_terminate')
   end
   % read out stuct value
   beta = zeros(Xr,Xc,'double');
   beta = s.beta;

   gamma = 0; % not given by you, but c-coder needs it. so change to what ever you need
end
```

Comment: Well, I'm afraid, but I guess coder.ceval will produce non compileable C-Code atm... but try.